HikariCP Creating New Connections Despite Idle Connections Available
I'm experiencing a strange behavior with HikariCP in my Spring Boot application. Even though there are idle connections available, HikariCP seems to be creating new connections instead of using the idle ones.
Below is my HikariCP configuration:
spring:
  datasource:
    hikari:
      connection-timeout: 30000
      minimum-idle: 20
      maximum-pool-size: 20
      idle-timeout: 10000
      max-lifetime: 30000
      auto-commit: false

The application runs fine for a while with the following status:
HikariPool-1 - Pool stats (total=20, active=0, idle=20, waiting=0)

However, when a large batch job is executed, a DB connection exception occurs. The problem is resolved when I increase the maximum-pool-size. The log then looks like this:
HikariPool-1 - Pool stats (total=24, active=4, idle=20, waiting=0)

My question is, why is my configuration creating new connections instead of using the idle ones when needed?
Expected status before I increased maximum-pool-size:
HikariPool-1 - Pool stats (total=20, active=4, idle=16, waiting=0)


Is there something wrong with my settings, or is there another issue I might be missing?
Additional Information:

Spring Boot version: 3.1.10

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

idle cannot be 16 as your minimum-idle is set to 20. Hikari will create a new one to fullfil the minimum-idle setting, increasing the total numbers of connections. Which after a while will be reduced again (the idle-timeout).

@M.Deinum Thanks for the explanation. Is my DB connection exception happening because minimum-idle and maximum-pool-size are the same, so no new connections can be created? I've read that setting them to the same value reduces connection creation overhead. Should I increase maximum-pool-size in my case to prevent running out of connections?
I'm still confused that my application works fine, but the status keeps showing active=0.

If there are no checkedout connections there are no active ones. You do mention an exception but not what exception, no stacktrace etc. Min idle is basically your minimal pool size, max the max. It will allow your pool to dynamically shrink/grow as needed.
